# Reverse line feed in Windows / Java

Tags: java, windows, command-line, console, linefeed

Is there a way to write several lines to the system console in Windows, then delete or modify them, using Java? I can write over the same line more than once using the `\r` carriage return character. The Cygwin command `less` (a text viewer) manages it (although it's not Java), so I suspect it's possible.

I've tried `\u008D` which is (according to a page I googled) the reverse line feed character, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    System.out.println("1");
    System.out.println("2");
    System.out.print("\u008D");
    System.out.println("3");
```

outputs

```
1
2
?3
```

whereas I'd hoped to see

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `System.out.print("\b");` It doesn't work in eclipse ([bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936) - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095986/how-to-get-backspace-b-to-work-in-eclipses-console) ) but should work otherwise.

Comment: This is an eclipse issue. Everything should work just fine in standard windows cmd console

Answer (score 1):

The [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) library can give more advanced console control when nothing else works.  Be aware that it uses native code.

The [killLine()](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/ConsoleReader.html#killLine%28%29) method may be what you are after if you end up using JLine.