# Java - Is it possible to keep printing text on the same line you enter a number on?

Tags: java, newline

I want to be able to enter a number using *nextInt()* and then print text on the same line as the number I entered. For example...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
int x = scan.nextInt(); //After you press 'enter' it goes to the next line and keeps printing text
System.out.print("I want this on the same line as my number!");
```

And the output would look something like this:

```
Enter your number: 4356
I want this on the same line as my number!
```

Is there a way I can get the text to print right after the number? So it would look something like this?...

```
Enter your number: 4356 I want this on the same line as my number!
```

Comment: While I can't give you an answer, I suspect this is likely to be a console issue rather than a Java one *per se*.  When you hit the `Enter` key after inputting the number, it's the **console** that decides to move the cursor to the start of the new line - it's not Java that decides to do it.  So any solution will involve Java somehow changing the natural behaviour of the console and may well be environment-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
System.out.print("\rI want this on the same line as my number!");
```

But note that because the user has to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, there's no way (AFAIK) to go a line backwards and erase till the beginning of it.

Comment: This will not print the number on the previous line, but will print the result and then insert a line b/w the Previous line and the result line.

Comment: Tried. Still printing on next line and not on same line.

Comment: @Logan - Strange! It works perfectly for me! Just put these three lines in a main and run it from command prompt:

System.out.print("Hello World:");
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.print("\rHey, this is me speaking...");

Comment: @Logan - the problem is when we read input from the user. The user has to press the "Enter" key for that. We can't go a line back up and remove the enter.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, I'm pretty sure the answer is "no", because there doesn't seem to be any reverse line feed (see this question: [Reverse line feed in Windows / Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756082/reverse-line-feed-in-windows-java)).