# How to delete previous character printed to console/terminal?

Tags: java

Is there a way to dynamically change output in Java? For instance, in a terminal window if I have:

```
System.out.print("H")
```

and then I have:

```
System.out.print("I")
```

The output will be:

```
HI
```

Is there a way to assign a position to outputs that allows you to replace characters dynamically? For instance (and I know this would not output what I want, I merely want to demonstrate my thinking) this:

```
 System.out.print("H")
 Thread.sleep("1")
 System.out.print("I")
```

And it would first print out

```
H
```

and then after a second, replace the H with an I?

I'm sure this sounds stupid, I am just interested in dynamically changing content without GUIs. Can someone point me in the direction for this technique? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, in console you can't do that. You cannot omit the output that already has been displayed, without re-executing your code.

Comment: Ok thanks! That's all I needed to know then!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522022/how-to-delete-stuff-printed-to-console-by-system-out-println

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at

```
System.out.printf
```

Look at the example shown here: http://masterex.github.com/archive/2011/10/23/java-cli-progress-bar.html

edit:

printf displays formatted strings, which means you can adapt that format and change it for your needs.

for example you could do something like:

```
String[] planets = {"Mars", "Earth", "Jupiter"};        
String format = "\r%s says Hello";

for(String planet : planets) {
    System.out.printf(format, planet);
try { 
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }catch(Exception e) { 
        //... oh dear
    }
}
```

Using the formatted string syntax found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

As the comment says this solution is only limited to a singular line however dependent on your needs this might be enough.

If you require a solution for the whole screen then a possible solution would be (although quite dirty) would be to hook the operating system using JNA and get a handle on the console window, find its height and then loop println() to "clear" the window then redraw your output.

If you would like to read more then I can answer more questions or here is a link: https://github.com/twall/jna

Comment: A limitation of that example is that it only show how to redraw the current line.

Comment: I updated the post with some more content regarding printf and an alternate solution

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind: I believe `\r` merely moves the cursor to the start of the line. Meaning that it wouldn't delete everything you've written before – you're overwriting the previous characters instead. This means it's somewhat tricky to replace a line with a shorter line, you have to overwrite the rest with spaces.

Comment: (I just went and verified the above, that's indeed what happens.)

Comment: well \r stands for "The carriage-return character" and means it will return to the beginning of the line, if you wanted to clear the line for a shorter line you could use padding

System.out.println(String.format("[%-20s]", "Earth"));

will give you:

[Earth               ] (15 spaces after earth)

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying it's a problem with your answer, just that it's a nonobvious caveat that wouldn't show up with either the progressbar example or your sample code. (The text written gets progressively longer in both.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\b` to backspace and erase the previous character.

```
$ cat T.java
import java.lang.Thread;

public class T {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("H");
        System.out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print("\bI\n");
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
$ javac T.java && java T
I
```

It will output `H`, then replace it with `I` after one second.

Sadly, it doesn't work in Eclipse console, but in normal console it does.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need (uses carriage return '\r' to overwrite the previous output):

```
  System.out.print("H");
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.print("\rI");
```

Answer (score 1):

The C library that is usually used to do this sort of thing is called [`curses`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). (Also used from scripting languages that rely on bindings to C libraries, like Python.) You can use a Java binding to it, like [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/). Google also tells me a pure-Java equivalent is available, called [lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna).