# Java code to replace console character by successive character in a loop

Tags: java

I wanted to show progress bar in console by replacing old character by new character so that only one character will be shown at any given time.
Example:

```
        char[] progressBarChars = { '/', '-', '\\', '-' };
        for(int i=0; i<progressBarChars.length; i++) {
            System.err.print("\r"+progressBarChars[i]);//it is not replacing previous character in console. i don't want to see previous char in console
        }
```

Output: i should be able to see characters are getting replaced in a single line/place in console.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146640/how-to-delete-previous-character-printed-to-console-terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete previous character printed to console/terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146640/how-to-delete-previous-character-printed-to-console-terminal)

Comment: No, i dont need new line

Comment: *"but no use"* What does that mean? I mean other than it doing it so fast that you cannot see the progression? That's why the suggested links has code with `Thread.sleep(1000)` to slow it down.