# Updating variables that have been drawn to Command Line

Tags: java, variables, interface, cmd

Hello StackOverflow...

This is a difficult question to word but I will attempt my hardest.
Okay,
If I were to make a piece of software run in the command line that would show the status of certain variables, is there any way that I could update what is drawn without adding extra lines to the screen.

Example :

```
-----------------------------
|   COMMAND LINE INTERFACE  |
-----------------------------

VARIABLE 1 <TRUE>  // I would like to update this variable without creating extra lines
VARIABLE 2 <FALSE>

<--------------------------->
```

Thanks Guys, Hope you understand...

Comment: You're looking to rewrite to the screen in arbitrary locations?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. You could try to simulate it by clearing the output, but then again: how do you differentiate between the command line and the IDE's output?

Comment: I also don't believe it to be possible. The output is (at least, conceptually) a stream, and I don't think you can go back and forth in a stream.

Comment: If you use a library like [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) then you could do that. Whether that still counts as a commandline application is debatable however

Comment: Wild idea, add a number in front of each vars, print everything and ask what variable needs an update (with the number)

Answer (score 0):

You can wipe out contents on screen and re-write using System.out.println. This will give a feel that new lines are not being written. You can refer [How to delete stuff printed to console by System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522022/how-to-delete-stuff-printed-to-console-by-system-out-println)