# Java remove input text from console without clearing console

Tags: java, io, console-application

So basically I have input reader that looks like this:

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while (true) {
    String userInput = stdIn.readLine();
    if (userInput != null) {
        String message = username + ":" + userInput;
    }
}
```

When I enter some text in terminal for input let's say:

```
this is a test
```

And I hit ENTER it stays there. Is there any way for it to get automatically removed from console WITHOUT clearing the whole console ?

Comment: print `\r` followed by a lot of spaces or maybe an ANSI escape sequence?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the entire line print '\r' (carriage return)

or if you want to remove part of the output just use '\b' (back space) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522190/2148851)

Comment: When I read user input simply print `System.out.println("\r");` ? Because that doesn't work. Can you give me an example how to use it ?

Comment: @Marijus Are you using any IDE. Try directly from console

Comment: I'm doing this ubuntu terminal :\

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot as you currently treat the console as a line printer. You should however treat it as a terminal that accepts ANSI escape codes. One library that lets you treat the console this way is [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) but there are many others. Note that the console needs to recognize the escape codes for this to work (e.g. the normal Eclipse console does not).