# Error searching for word in file

Tags: java, file, filewriter, printwriter

In a file of randomly generated passwords my goal is to ask for a password, check the 'codes.txt' file to see if it exists, say 'LOGIN COMPLETE' for 5 seconds, delete the password, then close the files. When I reach the while loop I nothing works the way I need it to. It has all kinds of different results in various situation, none of which I can understand. I haven't even figured out how to delete the stuff on the console after 5 seconds have passed printing 'LOGIN COMPLETE'. If anybody could help me right now I would really appreciate it. My code is located below.

```
package password;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Password {

    public void creator() throws IOException { 

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("codes.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);

        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".toCharArray();

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < 51; x++){
            String word = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                word+=c;

            }
            out.println(word);
        }
        fw.close();
    }

    public void readit() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("codes.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        //prints each line in the file
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        input.close();
    }

    public void checkit() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        File checkFile = new File("codes.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("tempFile.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(checkFile);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);

        System.out.println("What is the password?");
        String word = input.nextLine();

        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if(line.equals(word)){
                System.out.println("LOGIN COMPLETE");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } else {
                out.println(line);
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        fw.close();
        checkFile.delete();
        tempFile.renameTo(checkFile);
    }
}
```

The main file is below.

```
package password;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Password pass = new Password();

        pass.creator();
        pass.readit();
        pass.checkit();
    }
}
```

I am a beginner at java so in order for me to understand the code please use simple beginners code.

Comment: How to delete what is on console will depend on the console.

Comment: `I haven't even figured out how to delete the stuff on the console after 5 seconds` This isn't even remotely trivial. Are you supposed to be using curses or something? Deleting stuff from a console is not a standard thing to do.

Comment: I just need to clear the output information given from System.out.println if that isn't clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522022/how-to-delete-stuff-printed-to-console-by-system-out-println

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've decided there isn't really a need to clear the console screen in Netbeans, and I'll just leave it as is. I do want to give the solution I got in the end for those confused on what I wanted and for anyone who might have the same problems as I did.

```
package password;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Password {

    //Makes 50 random passwords(ten characters using letters and numbers)
    public void creator() throws IOException { 

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("codes.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);

        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".toCharArray();

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < 51; x++){
            String word = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                word+=c;

            }
            out.println(word);
        }
        fw.close();
    }

    //prints passwords for 10 seconds
    public void readit() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("codes.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        //prints each line in the file
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        input.close();

    }

    //asks for password and if it's correct then states LOGIN COMPLETE and then adds exceptions to a temporary file then readds to main file then closes
    public void checkit() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        File file = new File("codes.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("code.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);


        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a password");
        String word = input.nextLine();

        //prints each line in the file
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = reader.nextLine();
            if (line.equals(word)) {
                System.out.println("LOGIN COMPLETE");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } else {
                out.println(line);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        fw.close();

        File file2 = new File("code.txt");
        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(file2);
        FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(new File("codes.txt"));
        PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(fw2);

        while (reader2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = reader2.nextLine();
            out2.println(line);
        }
        file2.delete();
        fw2.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Main File Below:

```
package password;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Password pass = new Password();

        pass.creator();
        pass.readit();
        pass.checkit();
    }
}
```