# C clock program

Tags: c

I was trying to create a clock program with c using the eclipse ide.
When I run the program it keeps executing every single count.
I used system("cls"). Also tried "clear"
It shows no error but it is not working. I want the screen cleared after every count. It is showing a ⍰ symbol sometimes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ElDL.png ---This is what I got.

```
int main(void)
{

    int hour,minute,second;
    hour=minute=second=0; 
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);  

    while(1) 
    {

        system("cls");  

        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n",hour,minute,second);  

        fflush(stdout); 

        second++;  

        if(second==60)

        {
            minute += 1; 
            second=0;   
        }

        if(minute==60)

        {
            hour += 1; 
            minute=0; 
        }

        if(hour==24)

        {
            hour=0;
            minute=0;
            second=0;

        }

        sleep(1); 
    }

       return 0;
```

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you clear the console screen in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-the-console-screen-in-c)

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Please describe what happens and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Since you make `stdout` unbuffered, you don't need the `fflush` call.

Comment: What operating system do you use?  `system("clear")` in Linux, `system("cls")` should work in Windows.

Comment: Side note: this clock will eventually go out of sync. Each cycle will take 1 second of sleep and then some more time for code execution, which will add up to the clock being late. You should probably read the system clock each time, or at least sync with it occasionally.

Comment: Are you actually running this in the command prompt or are you looking at the Eclipse output window?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I used  eclipse console

Comment: It's Java, but this may still apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301530/how-to-clear-console-in-java-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

try using `system("clear");`

Comment: Not Working,Harish

Comment: @AthulKrishna.S Please add details as requested in the comments on your question. Until then, we can only guess at what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to example published above you need only one line to display clock. It's easier to add carriage return:

```
while(1) 
{
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\r",hour,minute,second);  
        fflush(stdout); 
        ...
}
```

Comment: Still not working