# How to do I delete the console output after small amount of seconds

Tags: java

So lets say I have this:

```
System.out.println("HelloWorld");
```

What would I do to make it so the console deletes "HelloWorld" after 10 seconds.

Comment: The is not supported in direct Java. You would need to do OS calls. I think you would use JNI for something like this (although I know nothing about JNI) and I believe the logic would be different for each OS..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete stuff printed to console by System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522022/how-to-delete-stuff-printed-to-console-by-system-out-println)

Comment: please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console