# How to separate my output by comma in java

Tags: java, arrays

I made this program to calculate set of numbers

```
public void himpunanIrisan(){
     System.out.print("The Result is  {");
     for(int k=1; k<=setofB; k++){
         boolean Sama = false;
         for(int i=1; i<=setofA; i++){
             if(numberB[k] == numberA[i]){
                 Sama = true;
             }
         } if (Sama==true){
             System.out.print(numberB[k]+ ",");
     }
     } System.out.println("}");
 }
```

and the output will show like this

```
The Result is {1,2,}
```

is there any way so the other comma will disappear?

Comment: What is setofB and setofA ? please add there values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that you are just a beginner and trying to learn that's why I try to use basic level solution.

```
    public void himpunanIrisan(){
        int[] numberB = {0,1,2,3,4};
        int setofB = numberB.length-1;
        int[] numberA = {0,1,2,5,6};
        int setofA = numberA.length-1;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("The Result is  {");
        boolean initParam = true;
        for(int k=1; k<=setofB; k++){
            boolean Sama = false;
            for(int i=1; i<=setofA; i++){
                if(numberB[k] == numberA[i]){
                    Sama = true;
                }
            } if (Sama && initParam){
                initParam = false;
                stringBuilder.append(numberB[k]);
            } else if(Sama) {
                stringBuilder.append(",");
                stringBuilder.append(numberB[k]);
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.append("}");
        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    }
}
```

The Result is {1,2}

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```java
System.out.print(numberB[k]+ ",");
```

to this should work.

```java
System.out.print(numberB[k]+ (k < setofB ? "," : ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a joining collector would be easier and help you avoid reinventing the wheel. Additionally, converting the arrays to `Set`s would perform better than a nested loop over two arrays (O(m+n) instead of O(m*n), where m and n are the sizes of the two array):

```
Set<Integer> setB = stream(numberB).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(
        Arrays.stream(numberA)
               .boxed()
               .filter(setB::contains)
               .map(Object::toString)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea from [How to delete stuff printed to console by System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522022/how-to-delete-stuff-printed-to-console-by-system-out-println)

You can use

```
System.out.print("\b");
```

To delete the "," character from STDOUT (see link for how to make it work in eclipse). Or you can change the code to something like this for example:

```
public void himpunanIrisan(){
 boolean isFirst = true;
 System.out.print("The Result is  {");
 for(int k=1; k<=setofB; k++){
     boolean Sama = false;
     for(int i=1; i<=setofA; i++){
         if(numberB[k] == numberA[i]){
             Sama = true;
         }
     } 
       if (Sama==true){
         if(isFirst) {
            System.out.print(numberB[k]);
            isFirst = false;
         } else {
            System.out.print("," + numberB[k]);
         }
         
      }
 } System.out.println("}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) is really convenient for such cases.

```
public void himpunanIrisan(){
     StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");

     for(int k=1; k<=setofB; k++){
         boolean sama = false;

         for(int i=1; i<=setofA; i++){
             if(numberB[k] == numberA[i]) sama = true;
         } 

         if(sama) joiner.add(numberB[k]);
     }

     System.out.printf("The Result is {%s}", joiner.toString());
}
```

You won't have any extra comma at the end of the output.

Answer (score -1):

dellete last two Prints and add this* print in to seccond for loop :

System.out.println( numberB[k] + (k<setofB ? "," : " }"));

Comment: This is basically the same as Darkman's answer