# How create a print loading text like a linux terminal in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Im tryng create a print effect who looks like a Loading Linux Terminal using the Koltin language. 
I want a print show the sequence of a spin:

`-\|/-\|/-`

So after the sequence the word "-" will be fixed and print the next spin. 
I want a print for 10 times. 
OUTPUT:

> --------/

Comment: printing just sends it to output. you can't modify it after sending. Only add new text to it

Comment: And exist something to do to subscribe a output text in Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete stuff printed to console by System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522022/how-to-delete-stuff-printed-to-console-by-system-out-println)

Comment: Specifically, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522190/611819

Comment: Humm, so I can't clearing screen on terminal in Kotlin. Only put many new lines to make a ilusion of screen is clear. I understend, thanks for the answer.