# Java carriage to previous line

Tags: java, carriage-return

`\n` - is a new line in java, is it possible to get to the previous line from the current position?
For example, I want to print "this is for test"

```
System.out.println("this is for");
```

Now how can I append "test" to the previous line since println moved carriage to the next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.

You would normally use `System.out.print` for the first part instead and use a `println()` or a `'\n'` once you're sure your line ended.

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```java
print "\033[F\r" + "New String"
```

The trick is : `\033[F` is an [ANSI code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (which is supported by most terminals) to go back one line. Then, `\r` is to go back at the beginning of the line. You can rewrite it from there. You may need to pad it with white spaces to clear it correctly.

I don't think this is supported in the default console in Windows (`cmd`), but it is very likely it will work in the powershell. In Linux (and very likely MacOS), should work without any issue.

**UPDATE**

After 12 years since I posted this answer, it seems `\033[F` is no longer working in my tests. Perhaps at that time I did something else that I can't remember now. The `\r` works without issues for resetting the position, for example:

```java
static void progress(int current, int total) {
    double pp = Math.round((current / total) * 10000) / 100;
    System.out.print "\rProgress: " + current + "/" + total + " (" + pp + "%) ";
}
```

Which you can call in a loop to display a progress.

Comment: Are you sure `"\033[F"` is a valid escape in Java? Or should it be `"\u0033[F"`?

Comment: @Snackoverflow as far I can tell is a valid escape, but after performing some tests, it seems it is not longer working for me. Not sure what I did 12 years ago that seems to work. I will update my answer.

Comment: `\033[1F` works for me on Java 17 Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to 'go back a character' you can do `System.out.print('\b')`, but unless you do, go for the other suggestions of using `System.out.print` first then `System.out.println` as it's more easy to follow.

Also, bear in mind that there's apparently a bug in Eclipse that stops this working as intended: [How to get backspace \b to work in Eclipse's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095986/how-to-get-backspace-b-to-work-in-eclipses-console).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.print()` instead to remain in the same line and append test to it .

```
System.out.print("this is for ");
System.out.println("test"); //System.out.print("\n");
```