# System.out.print('\r') doesn't work

Tags: java, printing

My `\r` doesn't work for some odd reason. It won't go back to the start of the line:

```
char[] animationChars = new char[] {'|', '/', '-', '\\'};

public Main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.print("Processing: " + i + "% " + animationChars[i % 4] + '\r');

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Processing: 0% |
Processing: 1% /
Processing: 2% -
Processing: 3% \
Processing: 4% |
Processing: 5% /
Processing: 6% -
Processing: 7% \
Processing: 8% |
Processing: 9% /
Processing: 10% -
Processing: 11% \
Processing: 12% |
Processing: 13% /
Processing: 14% -
Processing: 15% \
Processing: 16% |
Processing: 17% /
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? \r\n are OS specific.

Comment: are you using an IDE?

Comment: Are the output in new lines as shown in the question or they are in the same line?

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse IDE right now, i didnt test the code from a batch file. Maybe i should do that huh?

Comment: I can verify that it works via a batch script. Its a eclipse problem. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095986/how-to-get-backspace-b-to-work-in-eclipses-console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the problem of eclipse, it will take \r as a new line character and will print a new line. Try using intellij or from the command line prompt. I just verified in intellij that it works on a Windows

[I think this bug must still be unresolved](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936)