# is it possible to edit text written on command prompt in java

Tags: java

I want to make a 2D game in java that is run on command prompt. However instead of redrawing the map as a character moves across it I wanted to see if there was a way to edit the the map already written

Comment: Sounds interesting. Good luck, and head back when you have a question!

Comment: And in what way is this related to editing text written in the command prompt? How are you visualizing the maze data?

Comment: Linux, Mac, or Windows?

Comment: @ChrisZhang It looks to me like he's creating a text-only game not unlike Nethack. So he would need to change what characters are showing in the command window as the character moves through the map.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code; you can use these escapes to move around the console, e.g. `System.out.print("\u001b[1;1fWhere am I?");` will print at the upper-left-corner. Not sure if it works on Windows, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do it can depend on the operating system used. But in general, it is surely possible to do what you want.

Typically you can for example use `\b` character (backspace) to go a position back on the console. Be aware that it [won't work in Eclipse though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095986/how-to-get-backspace-b-to-work-in-eclipses-console).

But what you really want is probably a library giving you a "Curses" port (not sure if there is a native Java one), or [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) perhaps?